# How to create a conditional directive in .net based on dlls or packages included in the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create re-usable extension methods for the **Startup** class for asp.net core.

One thing i'd like to do is to add all the different usings based on true/false inputs.

One example is **services.AddHttpsRedirection** inside the ConfigureServices method.

My problem is that this method requires adding the nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy**.

What I'm trying to do is add a preprocessor directive based on the presence of this package/dll.

From what I have researched, it seems I would need to use something like:

```
#if HTTPS_POLICY
   services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            //difference options
        });
#endif
```

But what I can't figure out is where I will be setting the **HTTPS_POLICY** symbol.

I've found 2 possible places:

1. Using the .csproj file i can set **DefineConstants** elements using a Condition attribute.
2. I can set conditional compilation symbols inside visual studio.

But I'm not even sure if these 2 things are different, they could be the same.

And for option 1, I don't know how to use the **Condition** attribute to look for the existence of a package reference or dll.

Also consider, I am creating a class library that will be used by other projects, and ideally I don't want those other projects to have to set conditional symbols and things.

Is this even possible to achieve, if so how?

Comment: If you have a reusable class library, it won't be recompiled by the consuming projects.  So conditional compilation won't work.  You could use reflection to attempt to load the assembly containing the target method and invoke it if the load succeeds.

Comment: I was hoping i wouldn't have to use reflection, but since startup is a one time thing it isn't so bad. 
So there is no way to tell the compiler to only try and resolve the method/assembly at run time?

Comment: No, that is what reflection is for.

Comment: "I am trying to create re-usable extension methods"? What kind of extension methods?

Comment: The startup.cs class doesn't  have an interface, and it's not always clear which methods to call. So I'm creating extension methods that takes mostly bool parameters to perform certain config (eg addHttpsRedirection) etc.